# Update database from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Is there a way I can update an Access database from text boxes in vb.net. My current program is capable of display the values from an Access database.

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim sql As String =
    "Select TOP 1 GEUR,GUSD FROM GBPtb WHERE Date= ?"

    Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString),
      command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection),
      adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

        connection.Open()
```

How can I modify this program in a way that the user will be able to edit the currency exchange rates from the textboxes in the program?

Comment: You can use Data Binding: `tbxGBPUSD.DataBinding.Add("Text",ds.Tables("rates"),"GEUR", true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)`

Comment: DataBinding**s**. Don´t you have intellisense?

Comment: It does bind successfully, however the values doesn't change. Also I added the Data binding just above the If statement. Sorry I'm new to this. Thank You for your help.

Comment: In which method is your code placed in? I recommend to add it in `Form1_Load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a button which serves as the Update button.
Open the connection again, create a new update query for example,

```
Dim updateStr As String ="UPDATE yourTable SET col1 = col1 + 1"
Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(updateStr,yourConnection)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Or make use of command builder where you can just call

```
adapter.Update(ds)
```